# Calculate Total resistance in the Circuit

Tags: parallel, series

So am trying to find the total resistance in the circuit and potential difference, and new to electronics and not sure if am doing this correctly ,any hlp would be great. Voltage source set to U=24v (edit)

To find total resistance in the circuit i did:

R1+R2=30+60Ω=90Ω series

R3+R4=120Ω+60=180Ω series

90*180/90+180=60 ohms

and to find potential difference i did :

R1+R2=90Ω

24v/90Ω=266mA

266mA*60Ω=15.96v

R3+R4=180Ω

24/180Ω=133mA

133mA*60Ω=7.98v

7.98v-15.96v=7.98v

[image]

Comment: Looks correct to me but for the fact you say U = 27V and then proceed to use 24V for your calculations.

Comment: @Unimportant o sorry , mistyped

Comment: Are you finding the voltage and resistance across A-B?

Comment: @HariKrishna trying to find total resistance in the circuit and potential difference  between points a and b

Comment: Resistance is measure between two points. Either you measured the resistance between positive and negative terminal of the power source or the resistance between A and B

Comment: Yeah your calculation for potential difference looks fine to me

Answer (score 2):

The potential difference across A and B is 8V. Your method is exactly correct and its just the approximations you used while dividing which made it slightly vary.

But then I could give you a different perspective. Look at the ratios of resistance connected in series, its 2:1 and 1:2. So in the circuit, voltage across them will be (1/3-2/3)*U. You could find without calculating the current. (Just the same thing , but you can calculate faster)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, the total resistance is given by:

$$\text{R}_\text{total}=\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)\text{||}\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)=$$
$$\left(30+60\right)\text{||}\left(120+60\right)=\frac{\left(30+60\right)\left(120+60\right)}{30+60+120+60}=60\space\Omega\tag1$$

So, the input current is given by:

$$\text{I}_\text{in}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}_\text{total}}=\frac{24}{60}=\frac{2}{5}=0.4\space\text{A}\tag2$$

So, the voltage at the points (with respect to the minus-terminal of the source) is given by (using the current divider formula):

- Point B:
  $$\text{V}_\text{B}=\frac{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}\cdot\text{R}_2=$$
  $$\frac{120+60}{30+60+120+60}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot60=16\space\text{V}\tag3$$
- Point A:
  $$\text{V}_\text{A}=\frac{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_\text{in}\cdot\text{R}_4=$$
  $$\frac{30+60}{30+60+120+60}\cdot\frac{2}{5}\cdot60=8\space\text{V}\tag4$$

And so the voltage difference is equal to: \$\text{V}_\text{B}-\text{V}_\text{A}=8\space\text{V}\$.